# Is it possible to store an attribute on a model, but is only accessible through the association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an ecommerce platform and was looking over the database design.

These are the models in my ecommerce site:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart, {:optional => true}
end


class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :phones
  has_one :user
end

 class Phone < ApplicationRecord
 has_and_belongs_to_many :carts # has join table with Cart
 has_and_belongs_to_many :orders
 end


class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, {:optional => true}
  has_and_belongs_to_many :phones #HAS join table with Phone 
end
```

My site is selling phones (`Model Phone`) to users (`Model User`), who put them in carts (`Model Cart`), and once the order gets submitted, an order gets created (`Model Order`).

I want to update the quantities sold by putting `@user.cart.phones` (`@user` = current user) into the Order model, after the purchase has been submitted and finalized. The trouble I'm having is how I should design the database schema in so that I can track the type of phone being sold, and how many of that particular phone were sold in the order.

I was thinking something along the lines of `@user.order.phones`, and have an attribute called quantity on the `Phone` model. The problem with that is that the Phone model would be accessible to all users, hence, it would overwritten the moment another user submitted their order.

My question is, is it possible to have an attribute on the Phone model, only accessible to `@user.cart` (i.e.: `@user.cart.phones.phones_sold` --> `.phones_sold` would only be available through `@user.cart` and would be unique for each user)? If not, how could I go about designing my Model/Database to include an order model that has information about each order (type of phone, and quantity sold) that's unique to each individual user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :phones
end

 class Phone < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :carts # has join table with Cart
 end
```

and this is a good start, but the trouble is the join table is not directly accessible to your application.

Do instead...

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cart_phone_links
  has_many :phones, through: :cart_phone_links
end

 class Phone < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :cart_phone_links
  has_many :carts, through: :cart_phone_links
 end

class CartPhoneLink < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :phone
end
```

This gives you the same functionality as `has_and_belongs_to_many` but because the new table is actually a table accessible by rails you can add other fields ot it that give more information about the relationship, such as `quantity`

This is generally why `has_many ... through:` is considered more flexible than `has_and_belongs_to_many`